# Select item from UL LI QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

We have a requirement where we have to select web element drop down using UFT. Below is how my HTML element look.

[image]

Here is the VB script code i have.

```
 Country=dictobj.Item("CountryOfCardIssuance")  
 strPage.WebElement("innertext:= Select Select Bahrain Egypt Jordan Kenya Kuwait Lebanon Mauritius Morocco Nigeria Oman Pakistan Qatar South Africa Tanzania Tunisia United Arab Emirates Other/Unknown Country ").Click
 Dim ele  ,options
 ele="innertext:= " + Country
 strPage.WebElement(ele, "index:=1").Click
```

I want to select country based on excel input value. Please assist.

Thanks,
Pani

Comment: Can you provide any link to that page? If not, can you post the html source code here? The answer provided here would be very vague if such details are not provided.

Comment: What is the behaviour you're seeing?